# Passing (or "persisting") objects between two Flask routes?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to pass objects generated on one route (`/index`) to another (`/ello`) so that I don't have to make duplicate queries.

The objects are generated on the `/index` route ...

```py
@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def index(x=None,y=None):
        persons = Person.query.filter(Person.id != current_user_person_id).all()
        person1 = random.choice(persons)
        person2 = random.choice(persons)
        x,y = pair_generator(person1,person2)

    return render_template('index.html',x=x,y=y)
```

... and manipulated on the `/ello` route:

```py
@app.route('/ello',methods=['POST'])
def ello():
    winner_id = int(request.form['winner_id'])
    winner_score = int(request.form['winner_score'])
    loser_id = int(request.form['loser_id'])
    loser_score = int(request.form['loser_score'])

    # ELO CALCULATIONS GO HERE; OMITTED FOR BREVITY

    winner_object = Person.query.filter_by(id=winner_id).first()
    loser_object = Person.query.filter_by(id=loser_id).first()
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Here is the relevant section of `index.html`:

```py
<form action="{{url_for('ello')}}" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="nickname" value="{{x.nickname}}"  />
  <input type="hidden" name="winner_id" value="{{x.id}}"  />
  <input type="hidden" name="winner_score" value="{{x.score}}"  />
  <input type="hidden" name="loser_id" value="{{y.id}}"  />
  <input type="hidden" name="loser_score" value="{{y.score}}"  />
</form>
<form action="{{url_for('ello')}}" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="nickname" value="{{y.nickname}}"  />
  <input type="hidden" name="winner_id" value="{{y.id}}"  />
  <input type="hidden" name="winner_score" value="{{y.score}}"  />
  <input type="hidden" name="loser_id" value="{{x.id}}"  />
  <input type="hidden" name="loser_score" value="{{x.score}}"  />
</form>
```

As you can see, I'm querying the Person table *twice*. Is it possible to pass Objects between routes? (Or "persist" them in some way?) That way, I could allow the `/ello` route to access and manipulate the two Person objects created in `/index`.

Really, I want to be able to do something like this:

```py
<form action="{{url_for('ello', winner_object=x, loser_object=y)}}" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="{{x.nickname}}"  />
</form>
<form action="{{url_for('ello', winner_object=y, loser_object=x)}}" method="post"
  <input type="submit" value="{{y.nickname}}"  />
</form>
```

... but this of course passes the **strings**, not the objects:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/ello?  
winner_object=<app.Person+object+at+0x1062b1290>&loser_object=<app.Person+object+at+0x1062b1490>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and couldn't work out what is the correct method of doing it, so created a session and then had this variable available on every page.

Comment: Hm, yes, interesting but my objects change on every page refresh. More importantly though, the objects are two people (Person instances) and the user chooses which of these two people he'd rather spend time with. So, I need to know which of the two objects is selected as the "winner" in each round.

Comment: I came across 'g' yesterday but didn't have time to test it myself. Try looking up: from flask import Flask, g